# What is the algorithm to find a closest combination of multiple values to a limit?

Tags: algorithm

Please, hint me what is the effective algorithm to solve such problem:

1) have a limit number (e.g. 100)

2) have multiple candidates (e.g. 10, 15, 90, 70, 55)

a) we need to select 1 pair [i,j], such that the sum of the ith and jth candidates is closest but <=number

b) we need to select [i,j,k,...] canditates whose sum is closest but <=number

---

Just hint me, what to read, but if you are kind I appreciate  explanation right in answer
Thank you

Comment: I've edited your question to make it more comprehensible. Is that what you've wanted to ask?

Comment: I just had a quick look at your problems:
For part a, you can sort the list of candidates i.e. (10, 15, 55, 70, 90). Once, you have the sorted candidate list, then you can put two counter, one at the beginning and one at the end.  Try to experiment with this, and I think you would come up with solution.  
b) Intuitively, it seems to like 0-1 Knapsack, but I have not proved this translation https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Knapsack_problem#0/1_knapsack_problem

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**For the case of a pair:**

- You can find this solution in O(NlogN) time complexity; where N is the size of element list.
- Simply sort the list
- Then pick element from the left, and try to find the remaining value
  (key-picked) using a binary search. Attempt to find the value which
  is closest to the remaining, but doesn't exceed it.
- Do this for all N elements, and you will find the pair whose sum is
  the closest to the key maintaining Sum <= key.

Below I will put a sample implementation in C++

```
#include <bits/stdc++.h>
using namespace std;
#define NEG_INFINITY -999999

//In order to find a pair from item[] where the sumOfPair() <= key
pair<int,int> findPair(int* item, int len, int key)
{
    int* startAddr = item;
    int* endAddr = item + len;
    int firstElement, remaining;

    //Sort the given list
    sort(startAddr, endAddr);

    int closestFoundSum = NEG_INFINITY;
    int temporarySum;
    pair<int,int> pairForClosestSum = make_pair(NEG_INFINITY, NEG_INFINITY);
    pair<int,int> temporaryPair;

    /**
     * As the list is now sorted
        * for each element in the list starting from the left
        *   binary search for the remaining number in the remaining right partition of the list
        *   if any valid element is found
        *       check the sum, and always keep the largest sum that is <= key
    **/
    for(int i=0; i < len-1; i++)
    {
        firstElement = item[i];
        remaining = key - firstElement;
        startAddr = &(item[i]) + 1;

        int* foundAddr = lower_bound(startAddr, endAddr, remaining);

        if(foundAddr >= endAddr) foundAddr--;

        if(*foundAddr > remaining && foundAddr - 1 >= startAddr){
            temporarySum = firstElement + *(foundAddr-1);
            temporaryPair = make_pair(firstElement, *(foundAddr-1));
        }
        else if(*foundAddr == remaining && foundAddr >= startAddr){
            temporarySum = firstElement + *foundAddr;
            temporaryPair = make_pair(firstElement, *foundAddr);
        }

        if(temporarySum > closestFoundSum){
            closestFoundSum = temporarySum;
            pairForClosestSum = temporaryPair;
        }
    }

    //return the pair with the greatest Sum <= key
    return pairForClosestSum;
}


int main() {
    int item[] = {15,10,79,89,110};
    int len = 5;
    int key = 100;

    //For problem (a): Find a pair in the list with the closest sum to key; where sum <= key
    pair<int,int> resultPair = findPair(item, len, key);
    cout<<"Closest Sum of a Pair: " << resultPair.first<<" + "<<resultPair.second<<" = "<< resultPair.first + resultPair.second<<endl;

}
```

For the second case, ***find the closest sum taking any number of elements from the list***:
This is a classic 0/1 knapsack problem. It is a dynamic programming problem which is nicely explained here. [0/1 Knapsack](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/0-1-knapsack-problem-dp-10/)

Below I will put a sample implementation with commented code:

```
#include <bits/stdc++.h>
using namespace std;
#define ResetArr(arr) memset(arr, -1, sizeof(arr))

#define MAX_SIZE 10
#define MAX_SUM 1000

//memoization table
int memo[MAX_SIZE][MAX_SUM];

//list of elements
int arr[MAX_SIZE];

int findClosestSum(int index, int sumUptoIndex, int endIndex, int key){
    if(index >= endIndex){
        return sumUptoIndex;
    }

    //check memo table
    if(memo[index][sumUptoIndex] != -1){
        return memo[index][sumUptoIndex];
    }

    int sumConsideringIndex = 0;
    int sumAvoidingIndex = 0;

    //Check with taking element at 'index' into solution tuple
    if(sumUptoIndex + arr[index] <= key){
        sumConsideringIndex = findClosestSum(index+1, sumUptoIndex + arr[index], endIndex, key);
    }

    //Check without taking element at 'index' into solution tuple
    sumAvoidingIndex = findClosestSum(index+1, sumUptoIndex, endIndex, key);

    //take the sum that is closest and strictly less than key
    return memo[index][sumUptoIndex] = max(sumConsideringIndex, sumAvoidingIndex);
}


int main(){
    int size = 8;
    int key = 29;

    int arr2[size] = {5, 10, 17, 11, 12, 25, 4, 2};

    //fillup the list with given elements in arr2
    memcpy(arr, arr2, size * sizeof(int));

    //Do a 0/1 Knapsack Dp
    ResetArr(memo);

    cout<< "The closest {sum | sum <= key} = " << findClosestSum(0, 0, size, key) <<endl;

}
```

Answer (score 3):

**Hint:**

For the case of a pair,

- sort all values;
- scan from both ends using two "cursors"; move the left cursor; if the sum exceeds the limit number, move the right cursor.

E.g.

```
 10, 15, 55, 70, 90
  ^               ^
```

Done.